# Can I get Arabic language support in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to create a chatbot which supports Arabic and English. Is it possible to get the Arabic language support?

Comment: Desperately need Arabic in dilagflow

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,  there's no Arabic language support in api.ai for now. you can create multi-language bot at api.ai but it has the support of total 21 languages. A max of 15 locales can be added to an agent. English is default language when you create your agent. You can even add support for more languages later on. Please check out links 
https://dialogflow.com/docs/multi-language

[image]